# segmentation fault with accept() on linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, server

I have a problem with a client/server programm on linux. 
I wrote a server programm wich is sending data cyclic to one conneted client. 
Now I want to detect, if the client close the connection to the server. When the connection is closed from the client, i want to wait with accept(...) for an new connection.
Here the critical parts of my code:

```
error = send(client_sock, Zeichen, 1, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
if(error < 0)
{
    connected = 0;
    printf("Error, write on TCP Socket failed!!! Reconnecting... \r\n");
    close(serverSocket);
    initServer();
}

int initServer(void)
{
    int *new_sock;
    socklen_t size;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;

    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);       //Create socket
    if (serverSocket == -1)
    {
      printf("Could not create socket \r\n");
      return 0;
    }else
    {
      printf("Socket created \r\n");
    }

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IPAdresse);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(TCPPort);

    if(bind(serverSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)  
    {
      printf("bind failed. Error \r\n");
      return 0;
    }else
    {
      printf("bind done \r\n");
    }

    listen(serverSocket, 1);        
    printf("Waiting for incoming connections... \r\n");
    size = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
    printf("size of sockaddr_in: %i \r\n", size);
    client_sock = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &size);

   if (client_sock < 0)
   {
     printf("accept failed \r\n");
     return 0;
   }else
   {
    connected = 1;
    return 1;
   }
}
```

The first time it works fine, I can connect and can send data over the socket. When the client close the connection the error is detected, I close the socket an start the server again to wait for a new connection. But than I get a segmentation fault when I do the accept(..) for the second time!!! 
Can someone help me please!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Forget it. Your code is inside out and upside down. If the client disappears, it's his problem to reconnect to you, not the other way around. You should have an accept loop running somewhere else that ultimately reaches your send method. Not the other way round.

Comment: Use `perror` on syscall failures; also use `strace`

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're doing when the client connection closes.  I see no loop in your code, and yet you're suggesting that `accept()` is called more than once.

Without seeing the rest or the code, I can only speculate that:

- you're repeatedly calling `initServer()`, hence attempting to recreate the same server socket over and over (which, of course, would be bad),

or

- you're calling `accept()` again somewhere else in your code, most likely with corrupt arguments.

At the very least, what your server-side code should do is initialize the server socket once, then loop around `accept()`, like so:

- call `socket()` once
- call `bind()` once
- call `listen()` once
- then in a loop:

  - call `accept()`, this call will block until a client connects, and then return a connected socket,
  - do whatever you need to do with that (connected client) socket
  - resume with the loop